# SaveChanges in Edit action of MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

I'm a new to MVC and getting troubles with saving edited information of an action.
Every time I trying to SaveChanges I'm getting:
**Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.**

Here is my code:

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Profile(designer thisDesigner)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(thisDesigner).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return View(thisDesigner);
            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Profile");
    }
```

Also tried to query for new object and then to set and save the new values, in this case doesn't getting the exception, but the data is't saved.
Here is the code:

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Profile(designer thisDesigner)
    {
        designer updateDesigner = db.designers.Find(thisDesigner.designer_id);

        if (ModelState.IsValid && updateDesigner != null)
        {
            db.Entry(updateDesigner).OriginalValues.SetValues(thisDesigner);

            db.Entry(updateDesigner).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return View(thisDesigner);
            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Profile");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it working :)
Just needed to add all properties of my model to page, like this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.designer_id)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.designer_login_status)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.designer_register_date)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.designer_small_logo)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.designer_status)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.designer_vip_date)
```

And used same code from first example:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Profile(designer thisDesigner)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(thisDesigner).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return View(thisDesigner);
        }
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Profile");
}
```